# place call using Java with connected USB or HSDPA Dongle

Tags: java

i couldn't find any article upon "place call using java with a HSDPA Dongle" on google. i have done port initialization but don't know what to do for placing call.
1) i am using Huawei Dongle.

2) I have found error "NO CARRIER".

3) i am using the following code to detect port or modem and trying to place call but its giving me "NO CARRIER" error ! what mistake i am doing here kindly help me please

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import gnu.io.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.Main;
import sun.audio.*;

public class GSMConnect implements SerialPortEventListener, 
 CommPortOwnershipListener {

 private static String comPort = "COM6"; // This COM Port must be connect with GSM Modem or your mobile phone
 private String messageString = "";
 private CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
 private Enumeration portList;
 private InputStream inputStream = null;
 private OutputStream outputStream = null;
 private SerialPort serialPort;
 String readBufferTrial = "";
 /** Creates a new instance of GSMConnect */
 public GSMConnect(String comm) {

   this.comPort = comm;

 }

 public boolean init() {
   portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
   while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
     portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
     if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
       if (portId.getName().equals(comPort)) {
           System.out.println("Got PortName");
         return true;
       }
     }
   }
   return false;
 }

 public void checkStatus() {
   send("AT+CREG?\r\n");
 }

 public void dial(String phoneNumber) {
   try {
//dial to this phone number

     messageString = "ATD" + phoneNumber + ";\r\n";
     outputStream.write(messageString.getBytes());
     System.out.println("Called ");
   } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }

 public void send(String cmd) {
   try {
     outputStream.write(cmd.getBytes());
   } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }

 public void sendMessage(String phoneNumber, String message) {
       char quotes ='"';
   send("AT+CMGS="+quotes + phoneNumber +quotes+ "\r\n");
   try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    //   send("AT+CMGS=\""+ phoneNumber +"\"\r\n");
   send(message + '\032');
   System.out.println("Message Sent");
 }

 public void hangup() {
   send("ATH\r\n");
 }
 public void welcomeMessage(){

     // open the sound file as a Java input stream
        String gongFile = "C:\\Users\\SACHIN\\Desktop\\7001110.mp3";
        InputStream in;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(gongFile);
             // create an audiostream from the inputstream
           // AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
            // play the audio clip with the audioplayer class
           // AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
              Main.class.getResourceAsStream(gongFile));
            clip.open(inputStream);
            clip.start(); 
        } catch (IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





 }
 public void connect() throws NullPointerException {
   if (portId != null) {
     try {
       portId.addPortOwnershipListener(this);

       serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("MobileGateWay", 2000);
       serialPort.setSerialPortParams(115200,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
     } catch (PortInUseException | UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }

     try {
       inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
       outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();

     } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }

     try {
       /** These are the events we want to know about*/
       serialPort.addEventListener(this);
       serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
       serialPort.notifyOnRingIndicator(true);
     } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }

//Register to home network of sim card

     send("ATZ\r\n");

   } else {
     throw new NullPointerException("COM Port not found!!");
   }
 }

 public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) {
   switch (serialPortEvent.getEventType()) {
     case SerialPortEvent.BI:
     case SerialPortEvent.OE:
     case SerialPortEvent.FE:
     case SerialPortEvent.PE:
     case SerialPortEvent.CD:
     case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
     case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
     case SerialPortEvent.RI:
         System.out.println("Ringing");

    /*try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        send("ATA");
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    break;
     case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
     case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:

       byte[] readBuffer = new byte[2048];
       try {
         while (inputStream.available() > 0) 
         {
           int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);

           System.out.print(numBytes);
           if((readBuffer.toString()).contains("RING")){
           System.out.println("Enter Inside if RING Loop");    


           welcomeMessage();
           }
         }
         //readBufferTrial=readBufferTria;//+new String(readBuffer)+new Date();
         //print response message
         System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }
       break;
   }
 }
 public void outCommand(){
     System.out.print(readBufferTrial);
 }
 public void ownershipChange(int type) {
   switch (type) {
     case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_UNOWNED:
       System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_UNOWNED");
       break;
     case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_OWNED:
       System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_OWNED");
       break;
     case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_OWNERSHIP_REQUESTED:
       System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_INUSED");
       break;
   }

 }
 public void closePort(){

    serialPort.close(); 
 }

 public static void main(String args[]) {
   GSMConnect gsm = new GSMConnect(comPort);
   if (gsm.init()) {
     try {
         System.out.println("Initialization Success");
       gsm.connect();
       Thread.sleep(5000);
       gsm.checkStatus();
       Thread.sleep(5000);
       System.out.println("Before Auto Answer");
       gsm.send("ATS0=1");


       Thread.sleep(1000);
       gsm.dial("87SSSXXX9105");

     //  Thread.sleep(1000);
     //  gsm.welcomeMessage();
    //   Thread.sleep(1000);
     //  gsm.welcomeMessage();// for turning on Echo ATE1&W

       Thread.sleep(20000);

       gsm.hangup();
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       gsm.closePort();
       gsm.outCommand();
       System.exit(1);


     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   } else {
     System.out.println("Can't init this card");
   }
 }

}
```

Comment: Please show us your code and tell us at which step you are having trouble.

Comment: i have edited my question again, kindly check the code and tell me the mistake

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check if your HSDPA dongle really supports calls. A lot of HSDPA sticks only support SMS and data.

If it does and you have e.g. a virtual serial port you can connect from your Java program to it using e.g. Java RXTX and send AT-Commands like `ATDT01234567` (dial 01234567) to the stick.

Comment: thank you sir i done successully but  no sound is hearing !

Comment: Does the HSDPA stick add an audio device in the device manager? If not I would assume that only IP traffic is possible. With an LTE stick VoLTE (Voice over LTE - a special form of VoIP for mobile network) may be possible, but on HSDPA VoIP this is usually not supported by the carrier network (just the regular VoIP services  like Skype).